# What is the difference between string.replace(ch,'\0') and string.replace(""+ch,"")

Tags: java, string, replace

```java
class pola {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = "fast and furious";
        char s = 'f';
        System.out.println(name.replace(s, '\0'));    //---->line 1
        System.out.println(name.replace("" + s, "")); //---->line 2
    }
}
```

What is the difference between line `1` and `2`?

Comment: Why not to just read the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)? [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) would clearly tell you what's the difference.

Answer (score 8):

The first line calls [`replace(char, char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char))  and the second line calls [`replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)).

One big difference between those two methods is that the first one can only ever do 1-to-1 replacements of `char` values (i.e. each occurance of one char is replaced with exactly one other char), whereas the second one can replace an arbitrarily long string with another arbitrarily long string.

In your case:

- the first call replaces each `f` with a nul-character `\0`, effectively replacing each of them with an unprintable character.
- the second call replaces each 1-character string `"f"` with the 0-character `""`, effectively removing all `f` characters.

Comment: To see that there is a difference: compare the lengths of the resulting strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know both replaces the letter 'f'. I want to know what these two method has effect on the length of the string.

Comment: @i_am_ssr: that should be obvious from my answer: one keeps the same length, because it only does 1-to-1 replacement and the other removes all `f`, thus reducing the length.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer i was confused about the length part.

Comment: @i_am_ssr notice: don't expect this to behave like it would in C (i.e., adding a `'\0'` in the middle of a string would effectively truncate it). Java strings don't work like that, if that was your doubt.

Comment: yep you are right thats why i mixed it up @FedericoklezCulloca

Answer (score 0):

[Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) is almost always the best place to start with, whenever you're having questions concerning API design/details.

[`replace​(char oldChar, char newChar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char))

> Returns a string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

and

[`replace​(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in "ba" rather than "ab".

Answer (score 0):

The `null` character is still a character, and the *empty string* contains no characters - that is the difference in short.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more clearly if you print off the char arrays of each, in one the `f` characters are removed whereas in the second they are replaced by `\0`:

```
Arrays.toString(name.replace("" + s, "").toCharArray())
=> "[a, s, t,  , a, n, d,  , u, r, i, o, u, s]"

Arrays.toString(name.replace(s, '\0').toCharArray())
=>"[\000, a, s, t,  , a, n, d,  , \000, u, r, i, o, u, s]"
```